# How to bind queries that use variables for the LIMIT parameter in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, query-builder, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to fix a query in codeigniter, by binding queries for safety. But I am unable to use "`?`" in the limit parameter of the sql query.

Without using codeigntier's query builder, how can I fix this problem and still enable the queries to be escaped/safe?

**My CODE**

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT ?, ? ";

$bind  = array($one, $two) 
$query = $this->db->query($query, $bind);
```

The error I get is below

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?' at line 1`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

Remove `$id` from your `$bind` , since u r not using it anywhere in your `$query`

```
$sql= " SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT ?, ? ";

$bind  = array($one, $two);
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $bind);

/* to test 
 echo $this->db->last_query();
*/
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I was supposed to remove the `$id` from $bind, but I forgot, it was a typo. It sill doesn't work without the $id. Theres is something wrong with the use of `LIMIT ? , ? `. Any ideas how to fix this??

Comment: this is working correctly by my side and getting results also, there must be some error on your side

Comment: thanks, but its still not working. Codeigniter does not accept '? , ?'. can you please help